# Stack implementation in C

Tags: c, stack

```
typedef struct pilha Pilha;

struct pilha
{
    char metodo[31];
    Pilha *next;
};

void create_empty_stack(Pilha *Stack)
{
    Stack->next = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    Pilha *Stack;

    create_empty_stack(Stack);
}
```

Gives me an execution error.

What's the problem with this function?

Comment: @dreamlax:  it's a stack implemented as a singly linked list.

Comment: You say you get an error but you dont tell what error, why? What happens? Any error messages? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: You would do well to think about what you're trying to achieve when you say 'empty stack'. Do you want a stack with NO elements in it or ONE 'empty' element in it?

Answer (score 12):

This is a classic mistake that beginners do.

Let's take a look at your main function:

```
int main()
{
    Pilha* Stack; // This line is your problem!

    create_empty_stack(Stack);
}
```

If you remember pointers, the declaration `Pilha* Stack;` makes *Stack* be a memory pointer. But right now it doesn't point to anything, because you did not reserve memory for an object of type Pilha!

Your program crashes because create_empty_stack() tries to access *next*, a member of this object (remember that this object still doesn't exist).

So, what you should be doing instead is:

```
int main()
{
   // Reserve space in memory for one Pilha object and 
   // make Stack point to this memory address.
    Pilha* Stack = (Pilha*) malloc(sizeof(Pilha)); 

    create_empty_stack(Stack);
}
```

Or a much simpler approach:

```
int main()
{
    Pilha Stack; // Declare a new Pilha object

    // and pass the memory address of this new object to create_empty_stack()
    create_empty_stack(&Stack); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you'd better create your function like this:

```
Pilha* create_empty_stack()
{

    Pilha *Stack = malloc(sizeof(Pilha))
    Stack->next = NULL;
    return Stack;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an uninitialized variable `Stack` into the function `Criar_Pilha_vazia`. It will crash as soon as you do the first dereference on `Stack` in your function.

Comment: to be fair, the behavior is undefined. local variables are uninitialized or zeroed so theoretically you could get a valid pointer.

Comment: @luke  first time i heard of anti-Murphy .. is something even has an remote chance of going correct .. it just may !!!

Comment: Oh yeah. The worst thing it can do is *appear* to work. Then you go on and depend on it, and when other things don't work due to the dangling pointers you have a real mystery that can take a lot of effort to identify.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what `Stack` points to at the line in *Criar_Pilha_vazia()*.  The dereference for assignment points to a random place.  In a virtual memory environment, it will segfault.